# Correct argument specification in do.call

Tags: r

I'm struggling a little bit with do.call function. I'm running several different models on a data set.

For each model I would like to pass in the model function, a formula specifying the model, the function arguments, and the data set.

I hope it is clear what I want to do, in case not please leave a comment and I try to clarify my question.

My current code is a little bit to long, so here is a pseudo toy example:

```
methods   <- c('lm','glm',...) 
arguments <- list( list( 'Arguments lm '), list( 'Arguments glm '),... )
models    <- list( y ~. x1 + x2 , y ~. x1 + x3) 

for( i in 1:N ) { 

current.model <- do.call( methods[i], ??? ) 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(123)
dat <- data.table(x1=runif(10),x2=runif(10),x3=runif(10))
dat[,y:=x1+2*x2+3*x3+runif(10)]

>     dat
           x1         x2        x3        y
 1: 0.2875775 0.95683335 0.8895393 5.832886
 2: 0.7883051 0.45333416 0.6928034 4.675683
 3: 0.4089769 0.67757064 0.6405068 4.376344
 4: 0.8830174 0.57263340 0.9942698 5.806561
 5: 0.9404673 0.10292468 0.6557058 3.138048
 6: 0.0455565 0.89982497 0.7085305 4.448594
 7: 0.5281055 0.24608773 0.5440660 3.410939
 8: 0.8924190 0.04205953 0.5941420 2.975372
 9: 0.5514350 0.32792072 0.2891597 2.392937
10: 0.4566147 0.95450365 0.1471136 3.038589
```

I'm going to modify your structure a bit to make arguments an explicit list-of-lists and to name each element in the inner lists in order to remove ambiguity.

```
methods   <- c('lm','glm') 
arguments <- list( list(data=dat), list(data=dat,family="gaussian"))
models    <- list( y ~. x1 + x2 , y ~. x1 + x3)
```

`do.call` expects a function and an argument list. So I can do something of the form `do.call([an element of methods],[a list of arguments])`. Since the model itself is an argument, I'll need to join it to the "additional" arguments you supply in `arguments`. So I'll have some sort of object such as `c(list(models[[1]]),arguments[[1]])`. The `list` in the first argument turns the element `models[[1]]` into a list as `arguments[[1]]` is so that `c` can concatenate the two like lists. Finally, I can call `do.call` on these in your for loop, but `R`-style prefers `*apply` functions. Here I use `seq_along` which just gets me `1:length(methods)` and apply an anonymous function that does the body of the for loop; in sum this is essentially an abbreviated for loop that returns a list of the results:

```
lapply(seq_along(methods), function(n)
    do.call(methods[n],c(list(models[[n]]),arguments[[n]])))

[[1]]

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x1 + x2, data = structure(list(x1 = c(0.563014860032126, 
0.211994701065123, 0.174694777932018, 0.135693877004087, 0.460017150267959, 
0.736233349423856, 0.63450039527379, 0.652027820236981, 0.467176814330742, 
0.148995384806767), x2 = c(0.0307870297692716, 0.601646583992988, 
0.812958373920992, 0.698285705409944, 0.907962741097435, 0.75469194049947, 
0.0430496339686215, 0.0829190369695425, 0.109014765359461, 0.33699565846473
), x3 = c(0.412113963160664, 0.432729347608984, 0.0741072639357299, 
0.382540747756138, 0.0340626831166446, 0.624421828892082, 0.179525560466573, 
0.884322474710643, 0.548561444506049, 0.0785303884185851), y = c(2.22677680454217, 
3.11262330505997, 2.2728122510016, 3.08046812936664, 3.15304983314127, 
4.43124474911019, 1.85952415782958, 4.28254768694751, 2.72436442878097, 
1.10656954837032)), .Names = c("x1", "x2", "x3", "y"), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x7fbe1a050b78>))

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           x1           x2  
     0.8162       3.1206       1.6057  


[[2]]

Call:  glm(formula = y ~ x1 + x3, family = "gaussian", data = structure(list(
    x1 = c(0.563014860032126, 0.211994701065123, 0.174694777932018, 
    0.135693877004087, 0.460017150267959, 0.736233349423856, 
    0.63450039527379, 0.652027820236981, 0.467176814330742, 0.148995384806767
    ), x2 = c(0.0307870297692716, 0.601646583992988, 0.812958373920992, 
    0.698285705409944, 0.907962741097435, 0.75469194049947, 0.0430496339686215, 
    0.0829190369695425, 0.109014765359461, 0.33699565846473), 
    x3 = c(0.412113963160664, 0.432729347608984, 0.0741072639357299, 
    0.382540747756138, 0.0340626831166446, 0.624421828892082, 
    0.179525560466573, 0.884322474710643, 0.548561444506049, 
    0.0785303884185851), y = c(2.22677680454217, 3.11262330505997, 
    2.2728122510016, 3.08046812936664, 3.15304983314127, 4.43124474911019, 
    1.85952415782958, 4.28254768694751, 2.72436442878097, 1.10656954837032
    )), .Names = c("x1", "x2", "x3", "y"), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x7fbe1a050b78>))

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           x1           x3  
     1.6630       0.6408       2.4483  

Degrees of Freedom: 9 Total (i.e. Null);  7 Residual
Null Deviance:      9.518 
Residual Deviance: 4.269    AIC: 27.87
```

It's straightforward to drill down into your results. If I called that object `x`, then e.g. `x[[1]]` is the first fitted model, and I can use the standard suite of functions for interacting with it:

```
> coefficients(x[[1]])
(Intercept)          x1          x2 
  0.8162068   3.1205587   1.6057346
```